# How to get x, y distance from a circle

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

[image]

I've drawn a square shape whose width & length 20x, or 20y then I have drawn a circle inside the square whose radius 10x. Now a ray from the center of the circle went through the boundary of the circle at 45-degree angle (it can be 38 degrees or anything). Now how can i get x & y distance of connection ground of ray & circle from the square shape?

I've tried this code:

```
var radius = 10 //radius,
    x = Math.cos(Math.PI * 45 / 180) * radius
    y = Math.sin(Math.PI * 45 / 180) * radius
```

I'm not getting the exact distance with this code, what is the currect way to get this x & y distance?

Comment: Delowar - that was not a typo, that was "the bug"

Comment: You're not using `radius` in either of your equations

Comment: Pretty sure the math checks out now that you switched the variables to `radius`

Comment: does not anyone know the correct code to get the distance? please help me

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your coord origin is the top left of the enclosing square and the y axis is oriented downwards.

In that case,

```
var radius = 10 //radius,
    x = radius + Math.cos(Math.PI * 45 / 180) * radius
    y = radius - Math.sin(Math.PI * 45 / 180) * radius
```

Answer (score 2):

[update]
you can get the x & y distances using this formulas:

```js
var radius = 10 //radius,

var angle = 90

var d = Math.PI/180 //to convert deg to rads

if (0 <= angle & angle <= 45){
    deg = angle * d
    x = radius * Math.cos(deg)
    y = radius * Math.sin(deg)
}else if( 45 < angle & angle <= 90){
    deg = (90-angle) * d
    x = radius * Math.cos(deg)
    y = radius * Math.sin(deg)
}

console.log("x = " + x)
console.log("y = " + y)
```

If the angle is less than 45° we use the normal formulas as shown in the code.

But if the angle is greater than 45° we have to use the angle between the line and the y-axis which equal to 90-(angle value).

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the angle is  less than or greater than 45 degree then what can I do? I mean if the angle is 38 degree then is there any solution to get the x,y distance?

Comment: @Chems, this is only for the 45deg

Answer (score 1):

After someone's edit, your post contains the correct expressions for calculating x and y coordinates from the center of the circle ("from center" row in the table). In order to get the "remaining" part to the edges of its bounding square ("to border" row in the table), these distances can be subtracted from the radius:

```js
function calculate(){
  var radius=document.getElementById("radius").valueAsNumber||10;
  var radians=document.getElementById("degrees").valueAsNumber*Math.PI/180||0;
  document.getElementById("x1").innerHTML=radius*Math.cos(radians);
  document.getElementById("y1").innerHTML=radius*Math.sin(radians);
  document.getElementById("x2").innerHTML=radius-radius*Math.cos(radians)
  document.getElementById("y2").innerHTML=radius-radius*Math.sin(radians)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="radius" id="radius"><br>
<input type="number" placeholder="degrees" id="degrees"><br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br>
<table border="1">
<tr><th></th><th>x</th><th>y</th></tr>
<tr><th>from center</th><td id="x1"></td><td id="y1"></td></tr>
<tr><th>to border</th><td id="x2"></td><td id="y2"></td></tr>
</table>
```