# Calculate Wheel Data XY Position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styles

I tried to create a lucky draw wheel using reactjs, first, I need to place all the input data to a certain XY position. Below is the expected output XY position example what I need.

[image]

```
var renderData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];
React.createElement('div', { className: '_data'},
    renderData.map((index,item)=>{
        var itemPosition = index / renderData.length * 360;
        var itemX = itemPosition * Math.PI/180;
        var itemY = itemPosition * Math.PI/180;
        return React.createElement('div', { className: '_items',
            style:{top:itemX,left:itemY}
        },item);
    })
)
```

So I use `createElement` to create `div` for each of the data, then using `top` and `left` for XY position.

How to calculate the XY position for each `div`

**Update**

After tried the @keikai answer

```
var renderData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];
const r = 350;
const len = renderData.length;
const radiusList = renderData.map(x => (360 / len) * (x - 1));
const positionPairList = radiusList.map(x => ({
        x: Math.sin((Math.PI * x) / 180) * r,
        y: Math.cos((Math.PI * x) / 180) * r
}));
React.createElement('div', { className: '_data'},
    renderData.map((item, index) => {
        return React.createElement('div', { className: `_items`,
            style:{top:`${positionPairList[index].x.toFixed(2)}px`,left:`${positionPairList[index].y.toFixed(2)}px`}
        },item);
    })
)
```

[image]

1. all data are rotated 0deg
2. child div still not place to the right position inside parent div
3. for clockwise, it starts from 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get x, y distance from a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484631/how-to-get-x-y-distance-from-a-circle)

Comment: @keikai the link you mention, is provided 45deg for the calculation, I not sure how to calculate each degree for each data, and because the input data length might be different also.

Comment: Just replace the `45` to your calculated angel and it's done.

Comment: @keikai , as the comment above , I have mention I not sure how to calculate each degree angel for each data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: rotate display with clock styles

[image]

[image: Edit elastic-easley-1p5rj]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const n = 12;
  const r = 500;

  const radiusList = Array.from(Array(n).keys()).map(x => (360 / n) * x);
  const positionPairList = radiusList.map(item => ({
    x: Math.sin((Math.PI * item) / 180) * r,
    y: Math.cos((Math.PI * item) / 180) * r
  }));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {positionPairList.map((item, index) => {
        const offset = index === 0 ? n : 0;
        return (
          <div
            className="Parts"
            style={{
              top: `${r - item.y.toFixed(0)}px`,
              right: `${r + 200 - item.x.toFixed(0)}px`,
              transform: `rotate(${radiusList[index]}deg)`
            }}
          >
            {index + offset}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting the answer, there are two problem i face when try your answer, 1) all data are rotate 0deg 2) the value r is not equal the width of div parent right ? because my wheel is a big circle div (eg 700px) , I tried put half 350px for value r, but the child div still not place to the right position inside parent div

Comment: OK then forget about the 0deg, I updated my question with trying your answer, the x and y still not correct position, i use your x and y for top and left, it doesn't match with the parent div

Comment: for clockwise why it start from 10 ?

Comment: i can mark you as correct, seem your answer really help a lot, but it should start at 1 not 12 although it is clock wise , but not clock format, sorry about that

Comment: @FeelRightz If you want to start at 1, just remove the `offset` above.

Comment: what offset ? you mean the 200 ?