# Correct Wheel Data XY Position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the last question I asked [Calculate Wheel Data XY Position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59409182/4401349) , I have get the X,Y and Rotation for the `div` child.

Let say, the parent div width is `414px` , so I divide by 2 is `207` for `const r`

```
var renderData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];
const r = 207;
const len = renderData.length;
const radiusList = Array.from(Array(len).keys()).map(x => (360 / len) * x);
const positionPairList = radiusList.map(x => ({
        x: Math.sin((Math.PI * x) / 180) * r,
        y: Math.cos((Math.PI * x) / 180) * r
}));
React.createElement('div', { className: '_data'},
    renderData.map((item, index) => {
        return React.createElement('div', { className: `_items`,
            style:{
                top:`${r - positionPairList[index].y.toFixed(0)}px`,
                right:`${r - positionPairList[index].x.toFixed(0)}px`,
                transform: `rotate(${radiusList[index]}deg)`},
        },item);
    })
)
```

Below is the output result

[image]

**The child X and Y still no position in the right place, note that I cannot manually add the top or right position value, the value must use calculation.**

Comment: It looks like you need to use a smaller value for `r` and offset (add a little bit to) the x and y values.

Comment: Circle is just too small and center is moved to bottom left.

Comment: @AndrewMorton but i cant add the x and y value, it must be done in calculation, any suggestion ?

Comment: ...or too big - I don't know if you want the numbers inside or outside.

Comment: @Zydnar inside the grey parent

Comment: How did you get this value `r=207`? I think it should be calculated from something like parent.getBoundingClientRect() Also styling can be relevant to the question this bottom left shift can be CSS issue.

Comment: Try adding to `top:` and `right:` adjustRight, adjustTop - to see how big is shift - values of adjustRight, adjustTop can help you locate the problem.

Comment: @Zydnar that is a example value as I mention in question

Comment: The question stands how do you get the value - the way how you get height and width can be an issue? What about box-sizing property of parent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204567/discussion-between-zydnar-and-feelrightz).

Comment: @FeelRightz Like this: `const r = 190;` `x: Math.sin((Math.PI * x) / 180) * r + 20`. It is still using calculations.